# How to make List<List<int>> *.cshtml/razor - compatible?

Tags: c#, razor

In my `*.cshtml` file, I want to have something like

```
@List<List<int>> exps = new List<List<int>>(){ new List<int>(){1}, new List<int>(){2}, new List<int>(){3, 4}};
```

(`int` is to be replaced by a more sophisticated type...) When I run the page that contains the line above, I get `CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments` error.

Is it possible to fix the line of code above so that it works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is just incorrect razor syntax. That way it should work fine:

```
@{
    List<List<int>> exps = new List<List<int>>(){ new List<int>(){1}, new List<int>(){2}, new List<int>(){3, 4}};
}
```

The list then can be easily accessed over the view like this: `@exps`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps write it like this:

```
@{
    List<List<int>> exps = ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Razor engine might be getting confused. Try something like:

```
@{
    List<List<int>> exps = new List<List<int>>(){ new List<int>(){1}, new List<int>(){2}, new List<int>(){3, 4}};
}
```